# how to best emulate mobile for web dev

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

So, I've been doing some web deving using Chrome/Firefox responsive tools and going through the "devices" they got

However, there are things that look totally different:

[Firefox/Chrome responsive IPhone 6 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll2f4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zCa.jpg)

See how the hamburger menu is way larger on the actual device? Looks super different from the responsive one

Note¹: it happens on all low res mobile devices

Note²: I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. Tried couple others "meta" but none seem to do the trick

Note³: Tried to do the menu in two different ways, but both ended up like that

So, I was wondering, what's the best way to get a more accurate result of how it's going to look like in the mobile version

Thanks for helping! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate way is to use the actual device. A lot of mobile device emulating is just that, emulating the device - sometimes as poorly as shrinking the site via iframe.

Since we don't all have access to ALL of these devices, there are services like [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com) which have physical remote devices that you can render your site on, and in some even use DevTools. Unfortunately it does require a subscription after the free trial, but if you're concerned about pixel-perfect device testing, it's the best service I've found.

Outside of that you're stuck using native devices you own or browser-emulated devices which are far from perfect.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tought. It's a shame tho, was hoping to have a free way to test it better.